# Sending docker commands to Azure App Service for Containers

Tags: docker, containers, azure-web-app-service, seq

I need to map a file path in a third-party docker container (datalust/seq) to a file path in the hosting Web App.  More specifically, the /data folder in the container needs to be mapped to the /home/data folder in the Web App.

With a normal docker deployment, I can just use

```
docker run -v /home/data:/data
```

but how do I pass this to the docker container running in the Web App?  Afaik, the only thing that can be passed are App Settings, which are basically environment variables in the container.

I need this because the /home folder on the host (web app) is the only folder that can be persisted to Azure Storage, by using the WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE app setting.  This way, I want to persist the /data folder in the container.

Comment: Did you find the answer?

Comment: Unfortunately not...